# fridge gets too cold, freezer too warm

Tags: refrigerator

I've got an old school "up and down" fridge.

It freezes food in the fridge, regardless of what I set the thermostat to.

The freezer seems a bit on the warm side, ice cream seems very easy to scoop.

So basically veggies are freezing in the fridge, but it is dripping water down from the freezer at the same time.

It does do some refrigerating (and it does shut off eventually if I let it run).  So condenser system seems fine.

whirlpool w8txnwfwq00

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Common recommendations seem to be "make sure the thermostat isn't set to coldest" then "replace the thermostat" "replace the thermostat control board" "replace the main board"

In my case I don't have any control boards, that I know of.

I replaced the thermostat with a used one, same issue.  Replaced it with a "like new" one and the problem went away.

All 3 thermostat stills "tested fine" (it clicked on and off if frozen or heated).

Theory: the thermostat was "going out" so it would basically over cool, then wait too long before beginning to cool again.  Too wide of a range, as it were.  So the freezer would all melt before it would kick in again.  Then it would overcool again...

Comment: fyi ... that range between warm and cold sensing is called `deadband`

Comment: another name for that principle is hysteresis