# How can I find an air flow diagram for a refrigerator?

Tags: refrigerator

I am trying to diagnose a problem and want to know what the air flow is for an up-down fridge.  There don't seem to be many pictures online?

Comment: You may want to indicate what the problem is - there are a lot of folk here who may be able to help you diagnose it. Unless, of course, you're certain it's related to airflow...

Comment: I was trying to figure out if blocked airflow in the freezer was causing the fridge to get too cold.  In the end it wasn't.  https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/208351/fridge-gets-too-cold-freezer-too-warm/208352?noredirect=1#comment380532_208352

Comment: downvoters leave comments please, this was a legit question I had once so wanted to log the answer here for followers...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out you can find the air-flow diagram for "most any" fridge by looking in its manual.  Tricky to find in isolation.

For completeness, here's one:

[image]

Comment: Please come back to give your answer a check mark!